# Using variables with susy-breakpoint in susy 2

Tags: susy-compass, breakpoint-sass, susy-sass

I have recently upgraded to Susy2 and having to rework my base templates with new susy-breakpoints instead of at-breakpoint.

With the new susy-breakpoint I need to define a breakpoint and a layout for the short hand like so "60em, 12" and I have tried storing this in a variable e.g. "$large" so that I can pass it into various classes.

However as it is a single variable the mixin only sees it as one value so I can only store one value. Is there a way two store both values in a variable?

Answer (score 1):

Yep. Sass has [Variable Arguments](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#variable_arguments) which are great for handling this situation:

```
@include susy-breakpoint($large...) {
  // Your code here
}
```

The `...` does the magic.